# URL redirection upon parameters

Tags: php, url

I have a url pattern -- www.domain.info/(unique_number)

for example : http://domain.info/1211.10/09879 where **1211.10/09879** is a unique number

now ,on GET request I want to redirect this url to page.php where page.php will display unique_number's data.

where should i code for getting unique number from url?(i dont want to make directory -  1211.10/09878/)

what is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why redirect? Can't you just do that all on the same page?

Comment: Can you not send them to `http://domain.info/page.php?x=1211.10/09879` then access `x` in your `$_GET` array?

Comment: no. because i will look up into db for page.php. means where to redirect. it could be different server's url

Comment: downvoters - explain the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you must first configure the web server in order to send all requests to the same script, assuming you are using Apache this would be something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ routing.php [QSA,L]
```

This will send all requests that don't point to an actual file to the `routing.php` script.

Now in `routing.php` the identifier can be accessed through the global `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable:

```
// assuming the whole URL is http://domain.info/1211.10/09879?someParameter=someValue
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// remove the leading / and parameters:
$uri = substr($uri, 1);
if (strstr($uri, '?') !== false)
{
    $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '?'));
}

// Here $uri contains "1211.10/09879" and you can carry on
```

Comment: exactly what i want to do. how to configure web server to do this. i mean which config file i has to edit ?

Comment: Still assuming you are using Apache and local overrides are allowed in the global server configuration, you can put the above URL rewriting rules in a `.htaccess` file at the root of your web directory.